# I can't run this javascript code correctly

Tags: node.js, prompt

in this code:

```
var prompt = require('console-prompt');
var n = prompt('enter number');
for (let i=0; i < n; i++) {
    console.log("man khoshghlab hastam");
}
```

it doesnt work. at first is run the code completely and then I should enter number. how should I control it?

Comment: @Pierre Going by comment, its obviously js code being run on node.js not in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually going by the documentation of 'console-prompt', the prompt function returns a promise which fulfills when a value is entered in console and then hit return. So you should write the code something like this :

```
var prompt = require('console-prompt');
prompt('enter number').then((number) => {
  var n = parseInt(number);

  for (let i=0 ; i<n ; i++) {
    console.log("man khoshghlab hastam");
  }
});
```

Or you can use async await to do this :

```
var prompt = require('console-prompt');

async function something() {
  let number = await prompt('enter number');
  let n = parseInt(number);
  for (let i=0 ; i<n ; i++) {
    console.log("man khoshghlab hastam");
  }
}

something();
```